# How to increase the width of the bar (Kendo + Angular)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Currently am able to render bar chart using kendo angular bar chart component.
I need to increase the width of the bar dynamically, how can i achieve this functionality.  Please guide me on this.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the container width and call [`resize`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/resize):

```
$("#chart").width(100);
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").resize();
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uhuBUnar)